# How to find min and max value using xsl 1.0?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

file_1.xml

```
<productlist>
    <items>
        <item>Pen</item>
        <price>8</item>
    </items>
    <items>
        <item>Pen</item>
        <price>5</item>
    </items>
    <items>
        <item>Pen</item>
        <price>10</item>
    </items>
    <items>
        <item>Bag</item>
        <price>15</item>
    </items>
    <items>
        <item>Bag</item>
        <price>22</item>
    </items>
    <items>
        <item>Bag</item>
        <price>20</item>
    </items>
</productlist>
```

file_2.xml

```
<productlist>
    <items>
        <item>Pen</item>
    </items>
    <items>
        <item>Bag</item>
    </items>
</productlist>
```

need out put like below with max and min value using xsl 1.0

```
<productlist>
    <items>
        <item>Pen</item>
        <min>5</min>
        <max>10</max>
    </items>
    <items>
        <item>Bag</item>
        <min>15</min>
        <max>22</max>
    </items>
</productlist>
```

Answer (score 7):

Sort and then takes the first for the minimum and the last item for the maximum:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="data-url" select="'file_1.xml'"/>
<xsl:variable name="data-doc" select="document($data-url)"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="items" use="item"/>

<xsl:template match="@* |  node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="items">
  <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="item"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$data-doc">
      <xsl:for-each select="key('k1', $this/item)">
         <xsl:sort select="price" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
         <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
           <min>
             <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
           </min>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
           <max>
             <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
           </max>
         </xsl:if>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I apply above stylesheet with Saxon 6.5.5 on the input document

```
<productlist>
    <items>
        <item>Pen</item>
    </items>
    <items>
        <item>Bag</item>
    </items>
</productlist>
```

where the other file is

```
<productlist>
    <items>
        <item>Pen</item>
        <price>8</price>
    </items>
    <items>
        <item>Pen</item>
        <price>5</price>
    </items>
    <items>
        <item>Pen</item>
        <price>10</price>
    </items>
    <items>
        <item>Bag</item>
        <price>15</price>
    </items>
    <items>
        <item>Bag</item>
        <price>22</price>
    </items>
    <items>
        <item>Bag</item>
        <price>20</price>
    </items>
</productlist>
```

I get the wanted result

```
<productlist>
   <items>
      <item>Pen</item>
      <min>5</min>
      <max>10</max>
   </items>
   <items>
      <item>Bag</item>
      <min>15</min>
      <max>22</max>
   </items>
</productlist>
```

Answer (score 0):

10 years too late... but I found this question had a high rank in SO and the following might be an easier answer to follow if someone's still looking for a solution in XSL 1.0

Instead of the above "pure" XSL answer, you might simply be able to use the **math:min** function if it's available in your XSL 1.0 processor.

This works for me with Xalan 2.7.2 and Java 11 (openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16).

```
<xsl:variable name="minprice" select="math:min(productlist/items/price)"/>
```

<strike>You might need to specify the namespace xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math (but it wasn't necessary for me)</strike> I realized after answering this question that I was using XSL 1.1 which doesn't require the namespace to be declared. With XSL 1.0 you will need to declare it: xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math
(Thanks to @michael.hor257k)

among others, **math:max** also exists as a function, obviously to get the maximum value of an item in XSL 1.0.

By the way, the example XML in the question itself is incorrectly formed.

/price should close price, not /item

as in

<price>8</<strike>item</strike>>

should be

<price>8</price>

Comment: You most certainly MUST declare the namespace somewhere where it is in scope for the expression that uses the extension function.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Yes, you're right. I completely forgot that we were using XSL 1.1 in that particular area. Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can omit the namespace declaration in XSLT 1.1 either. Which processor did you use?

Answer (score -1):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="productlist"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="productlist">
        <productlist>
            <xsl:variable name="intermediate">
                <xsl:for-each-group select="items" group-by="item">
                    <items>
                        <item>
                            <xsl:value-of select="item"/>
                        </item>
                        <prices>
                            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                                <price>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
                                </price>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </prices>
                    </items>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:for-each select="$intermediate/items">
                <items>
                    <item>
                        <xsl:value-of select="item"/>
                    </item>
                    <xsl:for-each select="prices">
                        <min>
                            <xsl:value-of select="min(price)"/>
                        </min>
                        <max>
                            <xsl:value-of select="max(price)"/>
                        </max>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </items>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </productlist>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Nice.  If only the OP had not asked explicitly for XSLT 1.0!