# Get max Id from xml code using Xpath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have a XML file that contains two elements: `Project` and `Layer`. I want to get attribute `idLayer` with the highest number using java. My code is not working properly:

```
public int GetMaxID() throws JAXBException {
    try {
        XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
        String expression = "//Project/Layer/@idLayer[not(. <=../preceding-sibling::Layer/@idLayer) and not(. <=../following-sibling::Layer/@idLayer)]";
        XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile(expression);
        InputSource doc = newInputSource(newInputStreamReader(newFileInputStream(newFile("Projects//asdad//ProjectDataBase.xml"))));
        NodeList elem1List = (NodeList) xPathExpression.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        int maxId = elem1List.getLength();//give me 0
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return -1;
}
```

My XML code:

```
<tns:Project xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/ProjectDataBase" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/ProjectDataBase ProjectDataBase.xsd ">
  <tns:Layer idLayer="1">
    <tns:LayerName>tns:LayerName1</tns:LayerName> 
  </tns:Layer>
  <tns:Layer idLayer="2">
    <tns:LayerName>tns:LayerName2</tns:LayerName> 
  </tns:Layer>
  <tns:Layer idLayer="3">
    <tns:LayerName>tns:LayerName3</tns:LayerName> 
  </tns:Layer>
 </tns:Project>
```

Can you point me to the right direction?

Comment: You could always iterate through all the `<Layer>` elements and keep track of the one with the highest `idLayer` attribute. Not very elegant, though...

Comment: XSLT 2.0 knows the `max` keyword, so your XPATH could look like this: `max(//Project/Layer/@idLayer)`. For an equivalent XSLT 1.0 solution have a look at this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835990/how-to-find-min-and-max-value-using-xsl-1-0).

Comment: Your XPath expression does match the `idLayer` attribute of the last `<Layer>` element in your sample code - which is what you wanted. If the problem isn't in somewhere else, then could this be a namespace issue? Does your XML have any (default or prefixed) namespace?

Comment: yes content default namespace, I am sure my code is work because when I change instruction xpath to (".") then my code is work when i but instruction xpath ("same my code") is not give me any answer.

Comment: *I change instruction xpath to (".") then my code is work*, this does not rule out a namespace issue, `.` matches regardless of the namespace.

Comment: I add default namespace but my code not give me max id.please can you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the `tns` namespace. You don't use it in your XPath expression, therefore it cannot select anything.

There are countless examples of how to register XML namespaces with JDOM, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939636/how-to-use-xpath-on-xml-docs-having-default-namespace).

Also, your XPath is way too complicated.

Use `//tns:Project/tns:Layer[not(@idLayer < ../tns:Layer/@idLayer)]/@idLayer`.

Mind that this does not give *the* maximum node, but *all the* maximum nodes - there could be more than one.